# What does this nltk-boxer DRT output mean?

Tags: nlp, nltk

After much headache, I have finally managed to get Boxer and nltk boxer working. However, the output that I get from nltk boxer is somewhat different from what I was expecting. An example sentence like "Bob knows that John likes cows" should look like:

```
   __________________   ____________________  
  |x1 x2             | |x3 x4               | 
  |..................| |....................| 
 (|named(x2,bob,per) |+|know(x3)            |)
  |named(x1,john,geo)| |  Actor(x3,x2)      | 
  |__________________| |  Topic(x3,x4)      | 
                       |     ______________ | 
                       |    |x5 x6         || 
                       | x4:|..............|| 
                       |    |like(x5)      || 
                       |    |  Actor(x5,x1)|| 
                       |    |  Theme(x5,x6)|| 
                       |    |cow(x6)       || 
                       |    |______________|| 
                       |____________________|
```

But instead, it looks like:

```
 _____________________ 
| e1 p1 x1 x2         |
|---------------------|
| ne_geo_john(x2)     |
| ne_per_bob(x1)      |
| Topic(e1,p1)        |
| Actor(e1,x1)        |
| v_know(e1)          |
|     ______________  |
| p1:| e2 x3        | |
|    |--------------| |
|    | Theme(e2,x3) | |
|    | Actor(e2,x2) | |
|    | v_like(e2)   | |
|    | n_cow(x3)    | |
|    |______________| |
|_____________________|
```

Why is that?

Comment: Hello, where did you find boxer? :)